# Кнопка scroll-up в AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, прокрутка

На сайте [AngularJS Material](https://material.angularjs.org/) эта кнопка есть! Оформлена в виде **md-fab-button** - круглая красная внизу.

Никак не могу понять какой код у этой кнопки - в описании отсутствует..

**UPD:** Пример кода на AngularJS + Material без кнопки прокрутки (использую аналогичный код):

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    'use strict';
    const application = angular.module("application", ['ngMaterial']);
    application.controller('applicationCtrl', ['$scope', function(scope) {}]);
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="application" ng-controller="applicationCtrl" ng-init="onInit();" layout="column" class="ng-cloak" style="overflow: hidden;">

  <!-- Top menu -->
  <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools md-hue-2" md-scroll-shrink>
    <!-- Main -->
    <a href="https://example.com/">
      <md-button>
        <b class="md-title">Main page</b>
      </md-button>
    </a>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-content flex layout="column">
    <!-- Page header -->
    <div>
      <div layout="row" flex="100" md-whiteframe="1">
        <div flex layout="row" layout-margin layout-align="center center">
          <span class="md-display-1">Learning to write programs</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Page content -->
    <div layout="column" layout-padding layout-wrap style="flex-grow: inherit;">
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello world</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello space</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello universe</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello Santa Claus</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello stars</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello everyone</span>
      </div>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
      <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
      <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
      <!-- Divider -->
      <div flex></div>
    </div>
  </md-content>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел наконец-то код оригинальной кнопки!

Доступно по ссылке: [Material design for AngularJS | GitHub](https://github.com/angular/material).

Внутри используется незадокументированная фабрика **$mdUtil** для скрола, дополнительно кастомная директива **docsScrollClass** для визуальных эффектов и немножко кастомного CSS.

**НО!**

В моём случае этот код будет работать некорректно,

т. к. используется атрибут **md-scroll-shrink**, т. е. верхнее меню уезжает вместе со скролом.

---

#### Оригинальный код выглядит примерно так:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    'use strict';
    const application = angular.module("application", ['ngMaterial']);
    application
      .controller('applicationCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdUtil', function(scope, mdUtil) {
        let mainContentArea = document.querySelector("main");
        let scrollContentEl = mainContentArea.querySelector('md-content[md-scroll-y]');
        scope.scrollTop = function() {
          mdUtil.animateScrollTo(scrollContentEl, 0, 200);
        }
      }])
      .directive('docsScrollClass', function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function(scope, element, attr) {

            let scrollParent = element.parent();
            let isScrolling = false;

            // Initial update of the state.
            updateState();

            // Register a scroll listener, which updates the state.
            scrollParent.on('scroll', updateState);

            function updateState() {
              let newState = scrollParent[0].scrollTop !== 0;

              if (newState !== isScrolling) {
                element.toggleClass(attr.docsScrollClass, newState);
              }

              isScrolling = newState;
            }
          }
        };
      });
  </script>
  <style>
    .md-fab.docs-scroll-fab {
      position: fixed !important;
      transform: scale(0);
      transition: transform 0.2s;
    }
    
    .docs-scroll-fab.scrolling {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="application" ng-controller="applicationCtrl" ng-init="onInit();" layout="column" flex class="ng-cloak" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <main layout="column" flex>
    <!-- Top menu without md-scroll-shrink-->
    <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools md-hue-2">
      <a href="https://example.com/">
        <md-button>
          <b class="md-title">Main page</b>
        </md-button>
      </a>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content flex layout="column" md-scroll-y>
      <!-- Page header -->
      <div flex="noshrink">
        <div layout="row" flex="100" md-whiteframe="1">
          <div flex layout="row" layout-margin layout-align="center center">
            <span class="md-display-1">Learning to write programs</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Page content -->
      <div layout="column" layout-padding layout-wrap>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello world</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello space</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello universe</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello Santa Claus</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello stars</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello everyone</span>
        </div>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
        <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
        <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
        <!-- Divider -->
        <div flex></div>
      </div>
      <!-- Scroll up fub button -->
      <md-button class="md-fab md-fab-bottom-right docs-scroll-fab" docs-scroll-class="scrolling" ng-click="scrollTop()" aria-label="Back to Top">
        <md-tooltip md-direction="top">Back to Top</md-tooltip>
        <span>Top</span>
      </md-button>
    </md-content>
  </main>
</body>
```

---

#### Мой случай:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    'use strict';
    const application = angular.module("application", ['ngMaterial']);
    application
      .controller('applicationCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdUtil', function(scope, mdUtil) {
        let mainContentArea = document.querySelector("main");
        let scrollContentEl = mainContentArea.querySelector('md-content[md-scroll-y]');
        scope.scrollTop = function() {
          mdUtil.animateScrollTo(scrollContentEl, 0, 200);
        }
      }])
      .directive('docsScrollClass', function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function(scope, element, attr) {

            let scrollParent = element.parent();
            let isScrolling = false;

            // Initial update of the state.
            updateState();

            // Register a scroll listener, which updates the state.
            scrollParent.on('scroll', updateState);

            function updateState() {
              let newState = scrollParent[0].scrollTop !== 0;

              if (newState !== isScrolling) {
                element.toggleClass(attr.docsScrollClass, newState);
              }

              isScrolling = newState;
            }
          }
        };
      });
  </script>
  <style>
    .md-fab.docs-scroll-fab {
      position: fixed !important;
      transform: scale(0);
      transition: transform 0.2s;
    }
    
    .docs-scroll-fab.scrolling {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="application" ng-controller="applicationCtrl" ng-init="onInit();" layout="column" flex class="ng-cloak" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <main layout="column" flex>
    <!-- Top menu with md-scroll-shrink-->
    <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools md-hue-2" md-scroll-shrink>
      <a href="https://example.com/">
        <md-button>
          <b class="md-title">Main page</b>
        </md-button>
      </a>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content flex layout="column" md-scroll-y>
      <!-- Page header -->
      <div flex="noshrink">
        <div layout="row" flex="100" md-whiteframe="1">
          <div flex layout="row" layout-margin layout-align="center center">
            <span class="md-display-1">Learning to write programs</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Page content -->
      <div layout="column" layout-padding layout-wrap>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello world</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello space</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello universe</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello Santa Claus</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello stars</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello everyone</span>
        </div>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
        <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
        <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
        <!-- Divider -->
        <div flex></div>
      </div>
      <!-- Scroll up fub button -->
      <md-button class="md-fab md-fab-bottom-right docs-scroll-fab" docs-scroll-class="scrolling" ng-click="scrollTop()" aria-label="Back to Top">
        <md-tooltip md-direction="top">Back to Top</md-tooltip>
        <span>Top</span>
      </md-button>
    </md-content>
  </main>
</body>
```

---

### Решение:

Выносим кнопку за пределы **md-content** - оставляем в **main**. Фабрику **$mdUtil** и кастомный CSS оставляем без изменений - допиливаем директиву **docsScrollClass**, т. к. скролится у нас хорошо - отображается плохо.

Получаем следующую структуру:

```html
<main>
  <!-- Top menu with or without md-scroll-shrink-->
  <md-toolbar>
    . . .
  </md-toolbar>

  <!-- Page content with scroll -->
  <md-content>
    . . .
  </md-content>

  <!-- Scroll up fub button -->
  <md-button>
    . . .
  </md-button>
</main>
```

Такой код будет работать и с включенным, и с выключенным **md-scroll-shrink**:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    'use strict';
    const application = angular.module("application", ['ngMaterial']);
    application
      .controller('applicationCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdUtil', function(scope, mdUtil) {
        let mainContentArea = document.querySelector("main");
        let scrollContentEl = mainContentArea.querySelector('md-content[md-scroll-y]');
        scope.scrollTop = function() {
          mdUtil.animateScrollTo(scrollContentEl, 0, 200);
        }
      }])
      .directive('scrollClass', function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function(scope, element, attr) {

            let scrollMainChildren = element.parent().children();
            let isScrolling = false;

            // Initial update of the state.
            updateState();

            // Register a scroll listener, which updates the state.
            scrollMainChildren.on('scroll', updateState);

            function updateState() {
              // md-content element
              let newState = scrollMainChildren[1].scrollTop !== 0;
              if (newState !== isScrolling) {
                element.toggleClass(attr.scrollClass, newState);
              }

              isScrolling = newState;
            }
          }
        };
      });
  </script>
  <style>
    .md-fab.scroll-fab {
      position: fixed !important;
      transform: scale(0);
      transition: transform 0.2s;
    }
    
    .scroll-fab.scrolling {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="application" ng-controller="applicationCtrl" ng-init="onInit();" layout="column" flex class="ng-cloak" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <main layout="column" flex>
    <!-- Top menu with md-scroll-shrink-->
    <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools md-hue-2" md-scroll-shrink>
      <a href="https://example.com/">
        <md-button>
          <b class="md-title">Main page</b>
        </md-button>
      </a>
    </md-toolbar>
    <!-- Page content with scroll -->
    <md-content flex layout="column" md-scroll-y>
      <!-- Page header -->
      <div>
        <div layout="row" flex="100" md-whiteframe="1">
          <div flex layout="row" layout-margin layout-align="center center">
            <span class="md-display-1">Learning to write programs</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Page content -->
      <div layout="column" layout-padding flex>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello world</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello space</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello universe</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello Santa Claus</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello stars</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello everyone</span>
        </div>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
        <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
        <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
        <!-- Divider -->
        <div flex></div>
      </div>

    </md-content>
    <!-- Scroll up fub button -->
    <md-button class="md-fab md-fab-bottom-right scroll-fab" scroll-class="scrolling" ng-click="scrollTop()" aria-label="Back to Top">
      <md-tooltip md-direction="top">Back to Top</md-tooltip>
      <span>Top</span>
    </md-button>
  </main>
</body>
```

---

См. [«Scroll-up fab-button»](https://drakonoved.org/blog/2020/03/08/scroll-up-fab-button.html)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    'use strict';
    const application = angular.module("application", ['ngMaterial']);
    application.controller('applicationCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      let currentScroll = 0;
      let domScrolledBlock = document.querySelector('#scrolled');
      let domButton = document.querySelector('#toTop');
      $scope.scrollTop = function() {
        currentScroll -= 50;
        setTimeout(function() {
          domScrolledBlock.scrollTop = currentScroll;
          if (currentScroll > 0) {
            $scope.scrollTop();
          } else {
            currentScroll = 0;
          }
        }, 10);
      };
      angular.element(domScrolledBlock).bind('scroll', function(event) {
        currentScroll = event.target.scrollTop;
        buttonState();
      });
      const buttonState = function() {
        domButton.classList.remove('class', ((currentScroll === 0) ? 'show-button' : 'hide-button'));
        domButton.classList.add('class', ((currentScroll === 0) ? 'hide-button' : 'show-button'));
      };
    }]);
  </script>
  <style>
    .hide-button {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
      -ms-transform: scale(0, 0);
      transform: scale(0, 0);
      transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    .show-button {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
      transform: scale(1, 1);
      transition: 0.2s;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="application" ng-controller="applicationCtrl" ng-init="onInit();" layout="column" class="ng-cloak" style="overflow: hidden;">

  <!-- Top menu -->
  <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools md-hue-2" md-scroll-shrink>
    <!-- Main -->
    <a href="https://example.com/">
      <md-button>
        <b class="md-title">Main page</b>
      </md-button>
    </a>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-content flex layout="column" id="scrolled">
    <!-- Page header -->
    <div>
      <div layout="row" flex="100" md-whiteframe="1">
        <div flex layout="row" layout-margin layout-align="center center">
          <span class="md-display-1">Learning to write programs</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Page content -->
    <div layout="column" layout-padding layout-wrap style="flex-grow: inherit;">
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello world</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello space</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello universe</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello Santa Claus</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello stars</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello everyone</span>
      </div>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
      <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
      <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
      <!-- Divider -->
      <div flex></div>
    </div>
  </md-content>

  <button class="md-fab md-fab-bottom-right docs-scroll-fab md-button md-ink-ripple scrolling hide-button" type="button" docs-scroll-class="scrolling" ng-click="scrollTop()" aria-label="Back to Top" id="toTop">top</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Речь идет о плавной прокрутке и об исчезновении кнопки?

Comment: Я обновил код. Теперь это все с эффектами. Просто у версии angular material 1.1.20 еще нет предустановок с кнопками возврата наверх. Выпилил чисто ангулярским способом. Ни один jQuery не пострадал

Comment: Я достаточно досконально поискал и гугл намекнул, что каждый творит как может этот функционал. Чаще решения, конечно, через jQuery. Но это грубоватое решение. _Где-то лежат, но где_ - тот сайт AngularJS Material сам выполнен таким же способом. Логика открывания меню и прочие анимации лежат тут: `https://material.angularjs.org/latest/docs-demo-scripts.js`